# Transfer contents of map to a single vector of custom data structure

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, vector, stl

When I try to execute a program that calls my method I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) but I just cannot see the error. Have I made some kind of noob mistake?

```
#include<map>
#include<vector>
//#include<iostream>
//#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Record{
   public:
      T item;
      int total;
};

template <class T>
class Counter{
   public:
      map<T, int> m;

void printSummary(){

      typename map<T, int>::const_iterator itr; 
      vector< Record<T> > printlist;
      int i = 0;

      for( itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); ++itr ){
         printlist[i].item = (*itr).first;
         printlist[i].total = (*itr).second;
         i++;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printlist` is an empty `vector` when the following lines are executed:

```
printlist[i].item = (*itr).first;
printlist[i].total = (*itr).second;
```

which results in out of bounds access, causing undefined behaviour and in this case a segmentation fault.
Either use `push_back()` or create the `vector` with the required number of elements and leave the `for` loop as is:

```
vector< Record<T> > printlist(m.size());
```

Comment: If I use `push_back()` I believe it takes one argument so would I have to create a temporary `Record`, fill it with a key and value and then supply it to `push_back()`?

Comment: If you implement move semantics for `Record<T>` (which needs move semantics for T), then creating a temporary may waste close to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can access

```
printlist[i]
```

only if the vector has enough elements.  You could use another map to get a container with random access.